# Does my $_; do anything if $_ is implied

Tags: perl, lexical-scope

I think the answer is yes but I just want to make sure. so if I have

```
sub something {
    my $_;
    my @array = ...;
    while ( @array ) {
        say;
    }
}
```

is the `my $_;` actually effective at lexicalizing the parameter passed to the say?

In this particular case I'm using the [DZP::UnusedVarsTests](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Dist-Zilla-Plugin-UnusedVarsTests/lib/Dist/Zilla/Plugin/UnusedVarsTests.pm) and it's complaining that I haven't used `my $_;` and I suspect it's a bug since I'm using it in a case where it's implied.

Comment: Please don't do that. I'd hate to be the programmer who comes in after you and has to figure that out, especially since it's a very recent change to Perl. Why don't you just create a temporary, named loop-scoped variable?

Comment: This change is more than 2.5 years old, but using loop-scoped variable is a good idea.

Comment: I'd like to say I just coded up a quick example I have places that are not loops that I'm using the default argument.

Comment: As I understand it, the original implementation of the lexical topic has [been deprecated](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=119315). Added as an answer to another question http://stackoverflow.com/a/28945476/2019415 as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is Yes. It makes the functions in that scope use the lexically scoped `$_`, and not the global `$_`. If they write back to `$_`, as in the case of `s///`, you will have some level of damage control.

Per [`perldoc perldelta` (5.10.0)](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.0/perldelta.html#Lexical-%24_):

> "`List::Util::first`" misbehaves in the presence of a lexical `$_` (typically introduced by "`my $_`" or implicitly by "`given`"). The variable which gets set for each iteration is the package variable `$_`, not the lexical `$_` [RT #67694].
>
> A similar issue may occur in other modules that provide functions which take a block as their first argument, like
>
> ```
> foo { ... $_ ...} list
> ```

And, in [`perldoc perl591delta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl591delta.html#Lexical-%24_) it goes on to say:

> ### Lexical $_
>
> The default variable `$_` can now be lexicalized, by declaring it like
>   any other lexical variable, with a
>   simple
>
> ```
>      my $_;
> ```
>
> The operations that default on `$_` will use the lexically-scoped version of `$_` when it exists, instead of the global `$_`.
>
> In a "`map`" or a "`grep`" block, if `$_` was previously `my`'ed, then the `$_` inside the block is lexical as well (and scoped to the block).
>
> In a scope where `$_` has been lexicalized, you can still have access to the global version of `$_` by using `$::_`, or, more simply, by overriding the lexical declaration with "`our $_`".

## Examples

I wanted to provide some examples of why this functionality would be used:

```
my $_ = 'BOOM!';

sub something {
    my $_;                         ## Try running with and without
    my @array = qw/foo bar baz/;
    while ( $_ = pop @array ) {
        say;
    }   
}   

something();

say;
```

And, another example

```
my $_ = 'foo';

sub something {
  my $_ = $_;  ## Try running with and without
  s/foo/bar/;
  $_;
}

something();

say;
```

Comment: `perl591delta`?  A-ha!  No wonder `my $_` sounded so utterly weird.  I'm out of date and out of practice.  :(

Comment: Your examples show both HOW this functionality may be used and WHY it should never be used. If you find yourself writing my $_ then you are doing something wrong. If a package requires you to write my $_ then IT is doing something wrong.

Comment: @Matthew, if you're writing a package and you don't want bind all of the CORE operations to a named variable, you can localize the `$_` variable. I'm not suggesting this is a good idea, but only because I'm not totally convinced the idea of a default variable is a *good* idea. Certainly, the OO-base type is more appealing from a least-surprise stand point.

Comment: my personal opinion is that unless there's a technical reason... all these special variables should have been lexical by default anyways.

Comment: `$_` can't be lexical by default. A lexical can't be accessed outside the scope that defined it. (barring passing out a reference or closure)
Because of that code like `for (@arr) { print; }` would fail since print should not have access to the lexical `$_`. While it could be argued that perl internal function could cheat and access lexical copies of `$_` it would mean that there would be no way for a custom sub to behave like core functions. Instead of `my $_;` I have usually seen `local $_` which keeps one global `$_` and undoes any local changes when you exit your scope.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu, `$_` can be lexical yet accessible in a called function if the function uses the `_` prototype.  When the function is called, `$_` is aliased to an element of `@_` like any other argument. Try `perl -MData::Dumper -e 'sub foo(_) { print Dumper \@_ }; foo for 1..3;`

Comment: @daotoad that only solves half the problem. `map` and `grep` are special cased but user code using the `&` prototype is still broken if you use `my $_` for the reasons I stated.